# Bloom Shader Performance

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I found a simple and beautiful bloom shader from the Internet, but it is relatively slow.

By the looks of it, the culprit here is the nested loop and a texture lookup within it.

How could I make this run faster?

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
void main() {
    vec4 sum = vec4(0);
    vec2 texcoord = vec2(v_texCoords);
    int j;
    int i;

    for (i = -2; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = -2; j < 2; j++) {
            sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(j, i)*0.004) * 0.25;
        }
    }
    if (texture2D(u_texture, texcoord).r < 0.3) {
        gl_FragColor = sum*sum*0.012 + texture2D(u_texture, texcoord);
    } else {
        if (texture2D(u_texture, texcoord).r < 0.5) {
            gl_FragColor = sum*sum*0.009 + texture2D(u_texture, texcoord);
        } else {
            gl_FragColor = sum*sum*0.0075 + texture2D(u_texture, texcoord);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is the problem with bloom, it's slow because it queries the texture 25 times in that nested loop

Comment: This is a separable filter, sometimes two passes (horizontal and vertical) is quicker than 1 - particularly when you start to use larger sample windows (this is a 5x5 kernel). You may also benefit from exploiting hardware's built-in ability to quickly sample and average 4 texels at a time (linear filtering).

Comment: Err, now that I look more closely, this is a 4x4 kernel. Why are you doing this lop-sided? I think your loop should actually ***include*** I,j=2 rather than *ending* there. Ideally it would be split into two passes, so just I [-2,2] = 5 fetches per pass.

Answer (score 0):

I'm  unsure if 'manually optimized' GLSL makes any sense but  you may try to:

- unroll loops manually (for (i = -2; i < 2; i++), for (j = -2; j < 2; j++)), it'll give you 16 lines instead of 5 but 'optimized' code frequently looks 'not elegant', normally this operation should be done by compiler...
- store texture2D(u_texture, texcoord) in a vector
- do not repeat calculating sum * sum
- result should look similar to:

  `uniform sampler2D u_texture;
  varying vec2 v_texCoords;
  void main() {
      vec4 sum = vec4(0);
      vec4 col = vec4(0);
      vec2 texcoord = vec2(v_texCoords);
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-2, -2)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-2, -1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-2, 0)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-2, 1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-1, -2)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-1, -1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-1, 0)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(-1, 1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(0, -2)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(0, -1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(0, 0)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(0, 1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(1, -2)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(1, -1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(1, 0)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum += texture2D(u_texture, texcoord + vec2(1, 1)*0.004) * 0.25;
      sum *= sum;
      col = texture2D(u_texture, texcoord);
      if (col.r < 0.3) {
          gl_FragColor = 0.012 + col;
      } else {
          if (col.r < 0.5) {
              gl_FragColor = sum * 0.009 + col;
          } else {
              gl_FragColor = sum * 0.0075 + col;
          }
      }
  }`

  You may also consider searching for some more specific glsl optimization tips (texture fetch), optimizer tool etc.

Comment: you can also do the multiplication at the end of the sum

Comment: Unrolling the loop manually seems questionable. You don't know if the unrolled version is going to be faster on all architectures. The compiler should be able to make a much more educated decision on whether unrolling is beneficial. As @ratchetfreak points out, you could eliminate some operations. And the texture lookup for the central point is still done twice. But I suspect that it's all minor improvements. The 25 texture lookups will most likely dominate everything else.

Comment: Why 25? It's done for i, j : {-2, -1, 0, 1 } so "just" 16, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

one of the things I see in the shader is that it doesn't need to run when `col.r < 0.3` This means that with a stencil you can exclude those parts (so the shader will not run on those pixels) when running the bloom shader